# Sparql-gremlin tool don't use indexes

Tags: sparql, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I use sparql-gremlin 3.4.0 with janusgraph 0.3.1. After I create the index on vertex property 'iri', the gremlin query give an immediate result. Instead, if I excecute the same query in sparql, it not use any index.
In the example below I use the force-index option to avoid scan query.

[image: gremlin_sparql_query]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two issues to consider: (1) TinkerPop isn't properly optimizing that query to a state that JanusGraph can easily use an index or (2) JanusGraph isn't optimizing some aspect of the query to use the index. For the latter case, JanusGraph would have to nicely optimize `match()` step to use an index as that is the core step sparql-gremlin uses in its translation process. I'm pretty sure that it doesn't do that. Speaking to the former case, JanusGraph likely relies on TinkerPop to convert a `match()` into something easier to consume - in your example, hopefully JanusGraph would get to work with the query you wrote to initially test - `g.V().has('iri', ...)`. I think `explain()` would show you what's going on there as it did for me when I tested a variation of your example with TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> s.sparql("SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x v:name 'marko' }").explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [InjectStep([SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x v:name 'marko' }])]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [InjectStep([SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x v:name 'marko' }])]
SparqlStrategy               [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
EarlyLimitStrategy           [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
CountStrategy                [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(x), PropertiesStep([name],value), IsStep(eq(marko)), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,x)]
```

Not so good.

So, the options for a solution are:

1. JanusGraph needs to better optimize `match()` to handle this sort of query or
2. TinkerPop standard traversal strategies should be better at converting such queries to more general patterns or
3. `sparql-gremlin` should compile to Gremlin that matches more cleanly to existing traversal strategies

On that last point, note what happens if `sparql-gremlin` had generated this `match()` query instead:

```
gremlin> g.V().match(__.as('a').has('person','name','marko')).select('a').values('name').explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
==========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)]), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],v
                                      alue)]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)]), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],v
                                      alue)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)]), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],v
                                      alue)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)]), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],v
                                      alue)]
EarlyLimitStrategy           [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), MatchStep(AND,[[MatchStartStep(a), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)]), MatchEndStep]]), SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],v
                                      alue)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
CountStrategy                [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[~label.eq(person), name.eq(marko)])@[a], SelectOneStep(last,a), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([name],value)]
```

Much better. So, I tend to think that this is a general issue for TinkerPop to solve and it involves some combination of those last two points. Of course, it would be nice if JanusGraph optimized `match()` further if they could. None of this is a solution to your problem of course, but it should at least explain what's going on and where the problem is. I've created [TINKERPOP-2325](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2325) for further discussion and tracking.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the explanation, very clear. So it is a problem to be solved directly in future releases of Tinkerpop. Do you think that  can be a temporanely workaround to use the original code from LITMUS developed by the researchers?

Comment: i had the impression that the litmus code is behind the TinkerPop code at this point and that litmus depends on sparql-gremlin, so i don't think it offers any benefit. i could be wrong though

Comment: It is a wild guess, but try to add a `label` to your sparql query, so that resulting match would look like Stephen's: `?x v:label "person"`

Comment: you can try but i don't think it will matter. if i read the sparql-gremlin code right i don't think it will generate that way. i'd like to be wrong though :)

Comment: @KfirDadosh it gives the same result, even with something different from star-query.
stephenmallette probably you're right, Harsh Thakkar and the others researchers didn't have this issue because they used indices on Tinkergraph (which is in-memory) and not Janusgraph.

Comment: the indices won't even trigger on TinkerGraph as best i can tell.